# Effective use of QSettings

Tags: qt, qt5, settings, application-settings

I have quite a lot of settings in my program, about 3000.
They shouldn't be read at once upon the program's start, rather in 10 different places in the program when a need arises.
I wonder what is the **most efficient way in terms of performance/memory usage** to do this:

1 To have one 'global' QSettings instance always open;

2 To have some local QSettings instances in all the places where it is needed;

3 To read them once and to store them in memory for future use.

Or, probably, I am over-analyzing here and it doesn't really matter?

Comment: **most efficient way** - in terms of what - memory usage, speed of access, code maintainability?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: see my edit

Comment: Have you tried any of those methods and are having performance/memory issues?

Comment: I have got a legacy code where 3000 settings are scattered all over the code. I would like to create a kind of Settings Manager, and was wondering, what is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 5 years old, but I went into the source code for Qt and found that the QSettings constructor does literally nothing. It's just `{}`. All of the load goes on the functions for reading and writing data.